X [ERROR] Cannot redefine property: File [plugin angular-vite-optimize-deps]
I have a problem , when i tap the npm start or ng serve they start for me the localhost and after that they close it and show me a problem of :
`

X [ERROR] Cannot redefine property: File [plugin angular-vite-optimize-deps]

X [ERROR] Cannot redefine property: File [plugin angular-vite-optimize-deps]

C:\Users\HAMDALLAH\Desktop\Angular Projects\DemoApp\node_modules\vite\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1651
  let error = new Error(text);
              ^

Error: Build failed with 2 errors:
error: Cannot redefine property: File
error: Cannot redefine property: File
    at failureErrorWithLog (C:\Users\HAMDALLAH\Desktop\Angular Projects\DemoApp\node_modules\vite\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1651:15)
    at C:\Users\HAMDALLAH\Desktop\Angular Projects\DemoApp\node_modules\vite\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1059:25
    at C:\Users\HAMDALLAH\Desktop\Angular Projects\DemoApp\node_modules\vite\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1527:9
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  errors: [Getter/Setter],
  warnings: [Getter/Setter]
}




i tried to do the npm update to make an update on package.json but without any solution
